# How to parse inner child aray/object?

Tags: json, parsing

please do not close my case. I have submitted the same question  couple of times yesterday, but someone has posted a link. Am sorry for that, am very new to this coding. But i managed to print all the key and values of this Json, except the inner objects in th earray. I am spending hours in google searching for the same. below is th ecode i used to print all the values except inner values.

```java
Map results = (Map) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

Map Gtusage = (Map)results.get('QueryResult');
Map RtInfo = (Map)Gtusage.get('ContractInfo');
System.debug(RtInfo.get('ID'));
System.debug(RtInfo.get('Status'));
System.debug(RtInfo.get('Segment'));
Map RtInfo2 = (Map)Gtusage.get('SubscriberInfo'); 
//Map RtArr = (Map)RtInfo2.get('SubscriberProducts'); 
System.debug(RtInfo2.get('Status')); 
System.debug(RtInfo2.get('BillingType')); 
System.debug(RtInfo2.get('Name')); 
System.debug(RtInfo2.get('BSType'));
List RtInfo3 = (List)Gtusage.get('SubscriberProducts'); 
if (RtInfo3 != null) { 
    for (Object item : RtInfo3) {
        Map i = (Map)item;
        system.debug((String) i.get('Code'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('Status'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('DisplayName'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('ArabicDisplayName'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('Category'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('SubCategory'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('StartDate'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('EndDate'));
    }
}
```

This is my json output. From that, i want to get the inner object (product fee) and inner array elements(ProductSpecs).

```
{
    "QueryResult": {
        "ContractInfo": {
            "ID": "1684409",
            "Status": "Active",
            "Segment": "Consumer"
        },
        "SubscriberInfo": {
            "Status": "Active",
            "BillingType": "POST",
            "Name": "VAS  A S",
            "BSType": "VOICE"
        },
        "SubscriberProducts": [
            {
                "Code": "VCAF",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "Activation Fee Video Calls",
                "ArabicDisplayName": "gjhghghjg",
                "Category": "Video",
                "SubCategory": "Local",
                "StartDate": "2010-10-20T13:47:26.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Installation",
                        "Amount": "0",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Single",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "N_VC35-SUBS",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "KD35 - 5000 Minutes Plus 4G_500GB",
                "ArabicDisplayName": "5000 Minutes",
                "Category": "Bundle",
                "SubCategory": "Voice,SMS,MMS,Data",
                "Classification": "SUBS",
                "StartDate": "2017-05-31T23:59:59.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductSpecs": {
                    "ProductSpec": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Voice",
                            "Value": "5000",
                            "Measure": "Min"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "SMS",
                            "Value": "1000",
                            "Measure": "Unit"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "MMS",
                            "Value": "1000",
                            "Measure": "Unit"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Data",
                            "Value": "500",
                            "Measure": "GB"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Rental",
                        "Amount": "35",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Month",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "N_VC35-GPRS",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "KD35 - 5000 Minutes Plus 4G_500GB",
                "ArabicDisplayName": "5000 Minutes",
                "Category": "Bundle",
                "SubCategory": "Voice,SMS,MMS,Data",
                "Classification": "GPRS",
                "StartDate": "2017-05-31T23:59:59.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductSpecs": {
                    "ProductSpec": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Voice",
                            "Value": "5000",
                            "Measure": "Min"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "SMS",
                            "Value": "1000",
                            "Measure": "Unit"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "MMS",
                            "Value": "1000",
                            "Measure": "Unit"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Data",
                            "Value": "500",
                            "Measure": "GB"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Rental",
                        "Amount": "35",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Month",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "1-SHEFPR002",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "KD35 ATL Mixed Promotion",
                "StartDate": "2010-10-20T13:47:26.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Installation",
                        "Amount": "0",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Single",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "MSMU",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "MissU Monthly Subscription",
                "ArabicDisplayName": "MissU - poo",
                "Category": "VAS",
                "SubCategory": "MissU",
                "Classification": "MISSU",
                "StartDate": "2017-09-27T23:59:59.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Rental",
                        "Amount": ".5",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Month",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "PK00001",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "Mobile Services",
                "StartDate": "2010-10-20T13:47:26.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Installation",
                        "Amount": "0",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Single",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "MTVARAB",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "Mobile TV Arabic Package PostPaid",
                "ArabicDisplayName": "Mobile TV Arabic Package",
                "Category": "VAS",
                "SubCategory": "Streaming",
                "StartDate": "2015-01-08T23:59:59.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Rental",
                        "Amount": "3",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Month",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "Z00101",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "Postpaid Mobile Offer",
                "StartDate": "2010-10-20T13:47:26.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Installation",
                        "Amount": "0",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Single",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "FGRBT",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "RBT-SUBSCIPTION FREE",
                "ArabicDisplayName": "manga",
                "Category": "VAS",
                "SubCategory": "RBT",
                "Classification": "RPT",
                "StartDate": "2020-05-04T00:00:00.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Installation",
                        "Amount": "0",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Single",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "1-Q205",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "SIM",
                "ArabicDisplayName": "Multi SIM 2/3/4FF USIM Prep",
                "StartDate": "2010-10-20T13:47:26.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Installation",
                        "Amount": "5",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Single",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "FG50",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "Voice Mail Free Activation",
                "ArabicDisplayName": "vrithi",
                "Category": "VAS",
                "SubCategory": "Voice Mail",
                "Classification": "VOS",
                "StartDate": "2020-05-14T00:00:00.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": {
                    "ProductFee": {
                        "Name": "Rental",
                        "Amount": "0",
                        "RecurrencyType": "Year",
                        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                    }
                },
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "OFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Code": "DATASHARE",
                "Status": "ACTV",
                "DisplayName": "Internet Sharing service",
                "ArabicDisplayName": "arabicname",
                "Classification": "DS",
                "StartDate": "2017-05-31T23:59:59.001",
                "EndDate": "2020-06-30T23:59:00.001",
                "ProductFees": [
                    {
                        "ProductFee": {
                            "Name": "Installation",
                            "Amount": "0",
                            "RecurrencyType": "Single",
                            "RecurrencyValue": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "ProductFee": {
                            "Name": "Rental",
                            "Amount": "0",
                            "RecurrencyType": "None",
                            "RecurrencyValue": "0"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "Params": {
                    "Param": {
                        "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                        "Value": "NA"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex)

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for your responce. I have recieved this URL yesterday, but am comparing it with what i have done. and no clue how to get the inner object inside of an array

Comment: "ProductFees": {
                            "ProductFee": {
                                "Name": "Installation",
                                "Amount": "0",
                                "RecurrencyType": "Single",
                                "RecurrencyValue": "1"
                            }
                        },
                        "Params": {
                            "Param": {
                                "Name": "AutoRenewFlag",
                                "Value": "OFF"
                            }

Comment: which inner object inside the array are you referring to?

Comment: The "ProductFee" object inside the array "SubscriberProducts"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ProductFees returns 'inconsistent' structure, a map and list of map:

```
"ProductFees": {
    "ProductFee": {
        "Name": "Rental",
        "Amount": "0",
        "RecurrencyType": "Year",
        "RecurrencyValue": "1"
    }
},
```

```
"ProductFees": [
    {
        "ProductFee": {
            "Name": "Installation",
            "Amount": "0",
            "RecurrencyType": "Single",
            "RecurrencyValue": "0"
        }
    },
    {
        "ProductFee": {
            "Name": "Rental",
            "Amount": "0",
            "RecurrencyType": "None",
            "RecurrencyValue": "0"
        }
    }
],
```

You need to determine if the ProductFees is a list or map by using the `instanceOf` keyword.

```java
if (RtInfo3 != null) { 
    for (Object item : RtInfo3) {
        Map<String, Object> i = (Map<String, Object>)item;

        if (i.get('ProductFees') instanceOf List<Object>) {
            for (Object pf : (List<Object>)i.get('ProductFees')) {
                Map<String, Object> pff = (Map<String, Object>)pf;
                System.debug(pff.get('ProductFee'));
            }
        }
        else if (i.get('ProductFees') instanceOf Map<String, Object>) {
            Map<String, Object> pf = (Map<String, Object>)i.get('ProductFees');
            System.debug(pf.get('ProductFee'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Saved my Life

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct but the syntax that you have used does not work with apex.
You must mention the type while declaring the collections.

this does not work in the apex code

```
Map myMmap = new Map();
```

and this does work.

```
Map<String, Object> myMmap = new Map<String, Object>();
```

Same goes with the lists, you need to mention a list of what!

Final code

```
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
Map<String, Object> Gtusage = (Map<String, Object>)results.get('QueryResult');
Map<String, Object> RtInfo = (Map<String, Object>)Gtusage.get('ContractInfo');
System.debug(RtInfo.get('ID'));
System.debug(RtInfo.get('Status'));
System.debug(RtInfo.get('Segment'));
Map<String, Object> RtInfo2 = (Map<String, Object>)Gtusage.get('SubscriberInfo'); 
//Map<String, Object> RtArr = (Map<String, Object>)RtInfo2.get('SubscriberProducts'); 
System.debug(RtInfo2.get('Status')); 
System.debug(RtInfo2.get('BillingType')); 
System.debug(RtInfo2.get('Name')); 
System.debug(RtInfo2.get('BSType'));
List<Object> RtInfo3 = (List<Object>)Gtusage.get('SubscriberProducts'); 
if (RtInfo3 != null) { 
    for (Object item : RtInfo3) {
        Map<String, Object> i = (Map<String, Object>)item;
        system.debug((String) i.get('Code'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('Status'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('DisplayName'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('ArabicDisplayName'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('Category'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('SubCategory'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('StartDate'));
        system.debug((String) i.get('EndDate'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, The final code is the same code what i have now. The code prints all the objects inside the list RtInfo3. But the Array also contains an objects " ProductFee" insdie. But i do not know how to print that as well (or take the values of "Name": "Rental",
                                "Amount": "35",
                                "RecurrencyType": "Month",
                                "RecurrencyValue": "1")

Comment: @user84267 check the answer by Hengky Ilawan for that

Comment: Sure, Thanks Rahul.