# Responsive JSON data

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, restresource

[image]

Hi my requirment is :
In RestExplorer, Get Method, When i pass below URL #
/services/apexrest/partyInquiry?recordId=a1K2F000000Wsom
I can get Results below Structure :

```
{
  "caseInfo": {
    "partyId": "a1K36000",
    "productType": {
      "value": "Life"
    },
    "product": {
      "value": " Issue"
    },
    "carrierId": null,
    "stateId": "New York"  
  },
  "arrangement": {
    "arrangementNumber": "S03434555",
    "payrollBenefitDeductionFrequency": {
      "value": "11"
    },
    "endOfEnrollmentDate": "06/17/2020", 
    "isGIPolicyEnrolledinLast3Years": "YES",  
    "planType": {
      "value": " Issue"
    },
    "isSelectPaidUP": "YES", 
    "totalNumberOfProposedInsureds": 0 
  },
```

Pls see below my code :

handler class :

```
 public class ResponseGenerator implements IResponseGenerator {
       public Map<String, Object> generate(Id userId, IInquiryRequest request){
           return new Map<String,Object> {
               'arrangement' => new Map<String,Object>(),
               'caseInfo' => new List<Map<String, Object>> {new Map<String, Object>()}            
           };
       }
   }
   @HttpGet
   webservice static void InquiryRequestHandler() {
   Map<String, String> params = RestContext.request.params;
       system.debug('===========params:'+params);
       if(params == null || params.isEmpty()){
           RestContext.response.statusCode = 400;
           ErrorMessage[] messages = new ErrorMessage[] {
               new ErrorMessage('INVALID_REQUEST','no parameters')
           };
           RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
           RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(messages));
           return;
       }
       IInquiryRequest request = null;
       IResponseGenerator generator = null;
       system.debug('Inside If Condition1');
       /* figure out which mode we are in and sanity check parameters */
       if(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(recordId).toString().indexOf('atdHouseholdId') != -1){
           //this is a record id take household approach
           generator = new HouseholdResponseGenerator();
           request = new HouseholdInquiryRequest(recordId);
           system.debug('Inside If Condition2');
           // Code Notes
           String accountid='';
           Boolean isInsured = true;
           
           New_ApplicationDetailsCtrl.caseInfoWrapperRecords(applicationList);
```

controller class:   New_ApplicationDetailsCtrl

```
  global class caseInfoWrapper{
        global String partyId;
        global String productType;
        global String product;
        global String carrierId;
        global String stateId;
        
        global caseInfoWrapper(){
            partyId = 'a1K360000049LXMTC1A';
            productType = 'Whole Life';
            product = 'Simplified Issue';
            carrierId = '';
            stateId = 'New York';    
        }
    } 
    public Static List<caseInfoWrapper> caseInfoWrapperRecords(List<ATD_Application__c> applicationList){
        List<caseInfoWrapper> lsCaseWrappers = new List<caseInfoWrapper>();
        for(ATD_Application__c caseInfo : applicationList){
            caseInfoWrapper wrapper = new caseInfoWrapper();
            wrapper.partyId = 'PartyTestId';
            wrapper.productType = 'Life';
            wrapper.product = caseInfo.ATD_Plan_Type__c;
            wrapper.carrierId ='';
            wrapper.stateId = caseInfo.ATD_State__c;
            lsCaseWrappers.add(wrapper);
        }
        return lsCaseWrappers;
    }
```

Now i am getting Results are :

```
CaseInfo
  -- Item1.
```

Instead of Item1, i need to get JSON to Apex class values (PartyId,productType ,Product.....) and also arrangement data.
How to map the wrapper data to structure ( CaseInfo, arrangement)?

Comment: Your parameters don't match.  You are passing `caseRecord` on the URL but your Apex method expects `Id` as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted some of the key code here, but there's a clear pointer to the problem.

```
            return new Map<String,Object> {
                'caseInfo' => new List<Map<String, Object>> {new Map<String, Object>()}            
            };
```

You have, for reasons that are not clear from this code, mapped `caseInfo` to a `List<Map<String, Object>>`. That perfectly aligns with what you are seeing in Workbench, where you have a one-length array of values under `caseInfo`, so I presume this return value is also being returned from your `@HttpGet` method.

If your API is supposed to return multiple values, that's great. If not, then you need to change your top-level data structure to a single `Map<List, Object>`.

Comment: code updated ....and i mark my comments under method. How can i call JSON to apex class inside and populate other values.. thanks in advance

Comment: I really have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I modifed code and explain little bit clear . pls let me know if not understand my requirment ..Thanks

Comment: I mean, I think my answer still stands. That is the proximate issue. This code seems way over-complex to me. If you're new to working with JSON in Apex, see our [canonical resources](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex) for suggestions of patterns to use.