# Help with JSON.deserializeUntyped

Tags: apex, api, json

I am parsing JSON that is coming back from  REST callout, and when running, it is throwing this error: attemp to de-reference null object. The issue seems to be with how I am parsing the JSON, but I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can someone help?

Here is the snippet of the JSON I am parsing (bold parts are those that are causing the error):

```json
"result": {
"first_name": "JOHN",
"last_name": "SMITH",
"id_type": "MI",
"subscriber_id": "1234567",
"gender": "M",
"birthdate": "19601119",
"address": {
"info": "123 Main St.",
"city": "New York",
"state": "NY",
"zip_code": "100000"
},
**"county:": {
"value": "14"
},
"office": {
"value": "H78"
},
"recert_month": {
"value": "12",
"name": "December"
},**
"dates": [
{
"name": "Service",
"qualifier": "472",
"date": "2020-09-29"
},
{
"name": "Plan Begin",
"qualifier": "346",
"date": "2020-09-01"
},
{
"name": "Issue",
"qualifier": "102",
"date": "2020-06-01"
}
],
```

Here is how I am parsing it (bold part is causing error):

```
    Map<String, Object> wholeResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response2.getBody());
        Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) wholeResponse.get('result');
            Map<String, Object> residentAddress = (Map<String, Object>) result.get('address');
               **Map<String, Object> county = (Map<String, Object>) result.get('county');
              Map<String, Object> office = (Map<String, Object>) result.get('office');
             Map<String, Object> recert_month = (Map<String, Object>) result.get('recert_month');**
    
   Eligibility__c newEligRec = new Eligibility__c(); 
    newEligRec.Referral_Name__c = ref.id;
    newEligRec.First_Name__c = string.valueof(result.get('first_name'));
    newEligRec.Last_Name__c = string.valueof(result.get('last_name'));
    newEligRec.Name_Id_Type__c = string.valueof(result.get('id_type'));
    newEligRec.Client_ID__c = string.valueOf(result.get('subscriber_id'));
    newEligRec.Gender__c = string.valueOf(result.get('gender'));
    string birthdate;
          if (string.valueof(result.get('birthdate')) != null){
              birthdate = string.valueof(result.get('birthdate')).remove('-');
              string year = birthdate.substring(0,4);
              string month = birthdate.substring(4,6);
              string day = birthdate.substring(6,8);
             birthdate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
                }
    newEligRec.Date_of_Birth__c = birthdate;
    newEligRec.Address_Number_and_Street__c = string.valueOf(residentAddress.get('info')); 
    newEligRec.City__c =  string.valueOf(residentAddress.get('city'));    
    newEligRec.State__c =  string.valueOf(residentAddress.get('state'));    
    newEligRec.Zip_Code__c = string.valueOf(residentAddress.get('zip_code'));
    **newEligRec.County__c = string.valueOf(county.get('value'));
    newEligRec.Office__c = string.valueOf(office.get('value'));
    newEligRec.Recertification_Month_value__c = string.valueOf(recert_month.get('value'));
    newEligRec.Recertification_Month__c = string.valueOf(recert_month.get('name'));**
```

Comment: That line *cannot* throw a null pointer exception. Your problem is on a different line.

Comment: The lines that are throwing the null pointer exception are the last 4 lines (when I comment each one out individually, each of the others throw a null pointer exception.) I just meant to highlight the part of the JSON that I am having trouble with.  
newEligRec.County__c = string.valueOf(county.get('value'));
    newEligRec.Office__c = string.valueOf(office.get('value'));
    newEligRec.Recertification_Month_value__c = string.valueOf(recert_month.get('value'));
    newEligRec.Recertification_Month__c = string.valueOf(recert_month.get('name'));

Comment: Have you checked out our canonical QA, [How do I get started working with JSON in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex)? This JSON looks amenable to parsing with a wrapper class.

Comment: Are you certain that each message you receive contains the keys `county`, `office`, and `recert_month`?

Comment: I am certain it has county, but not necessarily office and recert_month. What would you recommend adding to the code to handle scenarios where it does not contain those keys? a try/catch block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These four lines are vulnerable to `NullPointerException`:

```
newEligRec.County__c = string.valueOf(county.get('value'));
newEligRec.Office__c = string.valueOf(office.get('value'));
newEligRec.Recertification_Month_value__c = string.valueOf(recert_month.get('value'));
newEligRec.Recertification_Month__c = string.valueOf(recert_month.get('name'));
```

If `county`, `office`, or `recert_month` is not present in the incoming message, each of these lines can throw a `NullPointerException` because, e.g.,

```
Map<String, Object> county = (Map<String, Object>) result.get('county');
```

is `null`.

You'll need to write conditional logic to check if these variables are `null` before you attempt to access their properties with `get()`, and presumably provide default values or decline to populate the linked field.

Comment: Ok- thank you!! I have another question re parsing this JSON- it is a basic question. Should I ask it here? My question is how to parse this section: "dates": [
{
"name": "Service",
"qualifier": "472",
"date": "2020-09-29"
},
{
"name": "Plan Begin",
"qualifier": "346",
"date": "2020-09-01"
},
{
"name": "Issue",
"qualifier": "102",
"date": "2020-06-01"
}
], and be able to get the string value of each one..
The first step is this: List<Object> dates = (List<Object>) result.get('dates'); but then how do I access each of the 3 objects in that list and their map key values?

Comment: I recommend looking at the canonical QA I linked above. I think it covers this area.

Comment: It doesn't look like it covers this area...

Comment: Basically you just have to keep calling `get()` and casting - or, better, use a statically typed wrapper class to deserialize.

Comment: I am a newbie to this so am not getting this. Here is what I'm trying:
          List<Object> lstdates = (List<Object>) result.get('dates');
          Map<String, Object> abc =  new Map<String, Object>();
                     abc.add(lstdates[0]);
but it won't let me save, saying: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(Object) from the type Map. I'm stuck on what to do, specifically, after this step "List<Object> lstdates = (List<Object>) result.get('dates');" esp. because each object within the "dates" list have same keys, so don't know how to differentiate with get()

Comment: You need to be _assigning_ lstdates[0] to abc, not creating a new Map.

Comment: Great- that is helpful, thank you!