# Why cant I cast my object to a wrapper?

Tags: apex

I have a list of Objects that I am trying to cast as with my wrapper class, when I run this I get the following error:

```
System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<ANY,ANY> to MyClass.LocationWrapper
```

This is what my class and wrapper look like:

```
public class MyClass {
 
    getLocations(List<Object> lcs) {
        for(Object lc : lcs) {
            system.debug(lc); // prints: {id:1122334455, label:Some Title}
            LocationWrapper locationData = (LocationWrapper) lc;
        }    
    }


    public class LocationWrapper {
        public String id { get; set;}
        public String label  { get; set;}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only cast between types that have an "is a"/"may be a" relationship with the other class.

Given these classes:

```
class Animal {...}
class Cat extends Animal {...}
class Dog extends Animal {...}
```

We can say that "Cat is a(n) animal" and "Dog is a(n) animal", "some Animal may be a Cat", and "some Animal may be a Dog", but we **cannot** say "some Cat may be a Dog", "some Dog may be a Cat", "Dog is a Cat", or "Cat is a Dog".

No custom class will ever share a "is a"/"may be a" relationship with a built-in class, as you cannot extend those classes. Even though the variable you're assigning *from* has all the properties that make up your class. You would need to specifically deserialize to that object in order for your cast to work:

```
LocationWrapper locationData = (LocationWrapper) 
  JSON.deserialize(
    JSON.serialize(lc), 
    LocationWrapper.class
  );
```

Generally speaking, you'll want to deserialize your JSON directly into the class (as demonstrated above), rather than serializing/deserializing a second time, as this is a costly operation (lots of CPU time). The above code is only illustrative. You would actually want to do something like:

```
LocationWrapper[] wrappers = (List<LocationWrapper>)
  JSON.deserialize(
    jsonSource, 
    List<Location>.class
  );
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't cast them because `LocationWrapper` and `Map<Object, Object>` are not compatible types. They have no inheritance relationship to one another. The fact that the Map at runtime has properties that correspond to the properties of the wrapper class is neither known to the compiler at compile time, nor expressed in the type of this value at runtime.

I assume this is ultimately coming from a JSON object. What you can do is use typed deserialization to produce a wrapper class instance *from the JSON*, rather than from the untyped Map that is produced by `deserializeUntyped()`.

There's not enough information here to provide a specific example, but the principle is illustrated in [this canonical QA](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex?r=SearchResults) about working with JSON in Apex.

The other option is write Apex code to take a `Map` and produce a `LocationWrapper` by copying the data from the Map. But that's not very efficient if you can just produce wrapper instances in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, the `lc` string has a single list of attributes. I'm not trying to cast a Map nor a List.