# Parsing of Json response from Tooling API code

Tags: apex, tooling-api, httprequest, http, httpresponse

Please have a look through the attached debug log [image: Debug Log]

Below is my code:-
Apex Class:-

```
             Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v50.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,EntityDefinition.developername,status+FROM+apextrigger');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' +userinfo.getSessionId());
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
      system.debug('3rd party response '+response.getBody());
            Map<String, Object> payload1 = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
         system.debug('List of Records '+payload1.get('records'));
        List<Object> items = (List<Object>)payload1.get('records');
    
        for (Object item : items) {
    
            Map<String, Object> i = (Map<String, Object>)item;
    
            System.debug(i.get('EntityDefinition'));
                }
```

Here I need to get the 'DeveloperName' from the Logs generated.What else i need to do in the above code?Basically i need to get the Id, developername, status field value from the endpoint url and display it in the table. Any inputs?

Comment: Have you read [How do I get started working with JSON in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex)? What specifically are you struggling with? It looks like you're most of the way to your goal already.

Comment: Yeah... I think I am almost there... It's just the last step I am struggling with... Let me try with the above post u both shared