# Updating json request before POST method

Tags: apex, api

I'm new in Salesforce using apex class for API with JSON. Here is my below JSON string which requires to updated first 3 value those are able to captured from VF page. Such as first value = 2 in place of 1 when the name = 'InPriorActs'

```json
{
    "inputCells": [
        {
            "name": "InPriorActs",
            "value": "1",
            "type": "NUMERIC"
        },
        {
            "name": "InProfCls",
            "value": "Accountants",
            "type": "STRING"
        },
        {
            "name": "InRevenues",
            "value": "150000",
            "type": "NUMERIC"
        }
    ],
    "outputCells": [
        {
            "name": "FinalModifiedRate",
            "value": "",
            "type": "NUMERIC"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help much appreciated!!

I'm able to update value in JavaScript  as below but this code not working in apex controller.

```javascript
        var jsonObj = strBody;
          for (int i=0; i<jsonObj.inputCells.length; i++) {
             if (jsonObj.inputCells[i].name == 'InPriorActs') {
                 jsonObj.inputCells[i].value = '2';
                 break;
             }
        }
```

I found soem help to use parcer which I coded as below but no luck to update it:

```java
JSON2Apex.InputCells[] inCells = new JSON2Apex.InputCells[]{};
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
           if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
             String currentPropertyName = parser.getText();
             if(currentPropertyName == 'inputCells') {
                parser.nextToken();
                if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONTOken.START_ARRAY) {
                   while(parser.nextToken() != null) {
                      if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONTOken.START_OBJECT) {
                         currentPropertyName = parser.getText();
                         if (currentPropertyName == 'value') {
                            JSON2Apex.InputCells iCells = 
       (JSON2Apex.InputCells)parser.readValueAs(JSON2Apex.InputCells.class);
                            inCells.add(iCells);
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
           }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] to show us the code you've written so far and the specific issue you're struggling with.

Comment: If you need help getting started with JSON in Apex, see [this canonical question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make a custom inner Apex Class to represent this object - `json2apex` can do this for you, but in this case you have a simple structure that can be hand built pretty quickly.

Something like this:

```
public class RequestContainer {
  public RequestItem[] inputCells {get; set;}
  public RequestItem[] outputCells {get; set;}
  
}
public class RequestItem {
  public String name {get; set;}
  public String value {get; set;}
  public String type {get; set;}
}
```

You would then get your JSON string and deserialize into this typed structure:

```
RequestContainer request = 
(RequestContainer)JSON.deserialize(JSONString,RequestContainer.class);
```

Then you could iterate and set your values as desired:

```
 for (RequestItem item : request.inputCells){
   if (item.name == 'InPriorActs') {
     item.value = '2';
     break;
  }
 }
```

NOTE: if you have system reserved words, the built in JSON parser will raise an exception. To get around this, you can replace all instances of say `type:` in your JSON string with, for example `itemType` perhaps.

If you are going to serialize again, after setting certain values, then you will need to do the reverse as well for sending in a callout.

Comment: Perfect Caspar!! Works like a charm what I wanted.