# Parse JSON Response - List of Objects

Tags: json, list, url, object

Disclaimer: I am new to JSON parsing in Salesforce, trying to up skill.

I am trying to extract the picture links, lets say the 'large' to be able to add to a contact record on record creation;

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/9.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/9.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/9.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have made a REST callout (https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&inc=picture&noinfo) via the following;

```
Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('callout:RandomUserGenerator/?gender=female&inc=picture&noinfo');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    // Sucessful, then parse response
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        Map<String, Object> jsonResp = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        List<Object> results = (List<Object>) jsonResp.get('results');
        
        for(Object res : results){
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = (Map<String, Object>) res;
            Map<String, Object> resultObj = (Map<String, Object>) resultMap.get('result');
            System.debug(resultObj.get('large'));
        }
                  
    }
```

The above is my latest attempt. I have also tried class variables (below) but in each approach I end up with null or 'doesnt exist' when trying to access the links.

```
public class Contact_JSON2Apex {
    public List<Results> results;
}

public class Results {
    public Picture picture;
}

public class Picture {
    public String large;
}

return (Contact_JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Contact_JSON2Apex.class);
```

Which method would the best approach? And how would one then access the individual link value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this answer, it explains JSON deserializing in a greater detail: [How do I get started working with JSON in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex)

Comment: There is no "result" property so this will return null `get('result')` .

Comment: Also you haven't defined `res` anywhere so it is null.

Comment: Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a pretty good first attempt. There's a few ways you can go about it. Personally, I like to use class deserialization due to its simplicity and type enforcement, unless there are things like reserved keywords to deal with. Here's my approach:

**JSON Class**

```
public without sharing class ResultsJSON {
   public List<ResultItem> results {get;}

   /**
    * Inner Classes
    */
   public class ResultItem {
      public PictureItem picture {get;}
   }

   public class PictureItem {
      public String large {get;}
      public String medium {get;}
      public String thumbnail {get;}
   }
}
```

The "without sharing" within the class definition isn't required, but good practice to indicate that your class doesn't require the application of sharing rules if not accessing any records within your org.

**Using the Class**

```
ResultsJSON response = (ResultsJSON)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, ResultsJSON.class);
System.debug(response.results[0].picture.large); // <= This should print the link for the "large" image
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much - that has cleared it up for me.