# Insert Key/Value Pair into Map<String, Object>

Tags: apex, map

I have an apex method that is calling an order detail api and returning a JSON response to the front end via something like this:

```
...
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
Map<String, Object> orderDetailJson = (Map<String, Object>) System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
```

Now I want to insert a separate key/value pair into that response. For example, let's say the orderDetailJson above is this:

```
{
    "cancelable": true,
    "order": {
        "orderId": "123456789",
        "orderItems": [{...}, {...}]
    }
}
```

I want to add `order.storeName = "Sears"`, so that the final `orderDetailJson` looks like this

```
{
    "cancelable": true,
    "order": {
        "orderId": "123456789",
        "orderItems": [{...}, {...}],
        "storeName": "Sears"
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This is much easier with typed deserialization: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can get complicated if you want to add something deeper down than the top level, because you end up having to do some [casting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting.htm) into other collections.

For example, to add an order item, you have to do something like:

```
Map<String, Object> orderDetailJson = (Map<String, Object>) System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
Map<String, Object> orderEntry = (Map<String, Object>)orderDetailJson.get('order');
List<Object> orderItems = (List<Object>)orderEntry.get('orderItems');
orderItems.add(new Map<String, Object>{
  'quantity' => 5,
  'productCode' => '12345'
});
```

Not terribly bad, but you have to understand the nature of your data structures to get anywhere. Casting to the wrong type will give you a runtime exception.

In your specific case, we want to add a value to the order, so we would write:

```
Map<String, Object> orderEntry = (Map<String, Object>)orderDetailJson.get('order');
orderEntry.put('storeName','Sears');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, Object> objectsByKey = (Map<String, Object>) System.JSON.deserializeUntyped( res.getBody() );
    Map<String, Object> orderByKey = (Map<String, Object>) objectsByKey.get('order'); // Extract the node you want to add fields from the main object
    
    orderByKey.put('storeName', 'Sears'); // Add values
    objectsByKey.put('order', orderByKey); // Replace the object into the first map
        
    system.debug('objectsByKey --> ' + JSON.serialize( objectsByKey ) );
```

Comment: Values are by reference, so you don't need to put the value back into the map.