# Apex Wrapper class instance field order

Tags: apex, class

```
// I have a wrapper class like:
public class classWrapper {
    public A A_ITEMS;
    public B B_ITEMS;
    public C C_ITEMS;
}

public class C {
    public List<CItem> item;
}

public class CItem {
    public String P;
    public String F;
    public String B;
    public String A;
    public String T;               
}
```

I want to create an event of this class like:

```
List<classWrapper.CItem> cIList = new List<classWrapper.CItem>();
classWrapper.CItem cI = new classWrapper.CItem();
cI.P = '1';
cI.F = '2';
cI.B = '3';
cI.A = '10';
cI.T = '7';
cIList.add(cI);
C_ITEMS.item = cIList;
```

Similarly for other two items of class then i want to convert this result in JSON string.

My issue is I want result in JSON string should be in same order as public String P;

```
 {"C_ITEMS":{["P":"1",
              "F":"2",
              "B":"3",
              "A":"10",
              "T":"7" ]}}
```

but I am  getting result as:

```
{"C_ITEMS":{["T":"7"
              "P":"1",
              "F":"2",
              "B":"3",
              "A":"10",
               ]}}
```

i.e. fields are getting sorted but I want them to be remain in same order as written in class definition.

Comment: JSON property order is strictly irrelevant since you can deserialize and access them directly by name. It's also not something you can control as covered in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/353615/is-the-json-serialization-of-an-apex-object-deterministic-repeatable) if you use `JSON.serialize`. Why is order important for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize and then manipulate the data. As long as all the data is returned, there shouldn't be any issue.