# Line: 15, Column: 1 System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, json

I don't know why this '[' is coming at the begining.I don't need this '[' at the begining due to which I am getting System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object

code

SOURCE ORG

```
    public class SendAttachmentByRestAPI {
        private final String clientId = 'clientid';
        private final String clientSecret = 'client secret';
        private final String username = 'username';
        private final String password = 'passwoed';
     public class deserializeResponse
       {
        public String id;
        public String access_token;
    }
    public String getAccessToken ()
    {
        String reqbody = 'grant_type=password' + '&client_id='+clientId +
                        '&client_secret='+clientSecret + '&username='+username + '&password='+password;
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
       req.setBody(reqbody);
        system.debug('reqbody'+reqbody);
       // req.setBody(JSON.serialize(reqbody));
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        deserializeResponse response = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
        system.debug('@@@@access_token@@'+response );
        return response.access_token;
    }
       public class deserializeResponse1
    {
        public String id;
    }
   public static void sendAttachement(){
        //get Access Tocken
        SendAttachmentByRestAPI accessTk = new SendAttachmentByRestAPI();
        String accessToken;
        accessToken = accessTk.getAccessToken();
        System.debug('accessToken==='+accessToken);        
        ContentVersion conDoc =  [SELECT Id, Title, VersionData, PathOnClient,ContentDocumentID FROM ContentVersion where ID= '0684W00000EWbOLQA1'];
       ID conDocument = [Select ContentDocumentID from ContentVersion where ID=:conDoc.ID].ContentDocumentID;
       system.debug('conDoc==='+conDoc);
        //get ContentVersion body
      //  String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(conDoc.VersionData);
          Id oppID = '0064W0000147uctQAA';        
        if(accessToken != Null){
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://datasirpicnat-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/getContentVersions/name=Murugan.JPG');
            //req.setEndpoint('https://datasirpicnat-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/getContentVersions/name='+conDocument);             
            req.setMethod('POST');
        //    system.debug('bodyEncoded===='+bodyEncoded);
            String reqbody1 = 'Title = '+conDoc.Title +'VersionData='+conDoc.VersionData + 'PathOnClient='+conDoc.PathOnClient;
            req.setBody(reqbody1);
            system.debug('reqbody1'+reqbody1);
            req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '  +accessToken);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
         //   req.setHeader('accept','application/json');
         //   System.debug('END-POINT===='+req.getEndpoint());
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            system.debug('res'+res);  
            string resBody=res.getBody();
            system.debug('res body'+resBody);
              system.debug('response getbody'+res.getBody());
         
            String trimmedResponse = resBody.unescapeCsv().remove('\\');
            list<deserializeResponse1> resp2 = (list<deserializeResponse1>)JSON.deserialize(trimmedResponse, list<deserializeResponse1>.class);
            Document_URL__c a = [SELECT Id,Name,Document_URL__c FROM Document_URL__c];
            a.Document_URL__c = resp2[0].Id;
            a.name = 'Response1';
            system.debug('a.Document_URL__c'+a.Document_URL__c);
            update a;
          } 
    }   
}
```

TARGET ORG

```
   @RestResource(urlMapping='/getContentVersions/*')
    global with sharing class ShareFileRest {
    
        @HttpPost
        global static String getFileToStore() {
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            system.debug('request'+req); 
            String name = req.requestURI.substring(
                            req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            String afterblob = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(req.requestBody);
            blob blogdecode=EncodingUtil.base64Decode(afterblob); 
            system.debug('blogdecode'+blogdecode);
      
      //insert contentVersion
            contentVersion cVersion = new contentVersion();
            cVersion.PathOnClient = name;   
            system.debug('PathOnClient'+cVersion.PathOnClient);
            cVersion.Title = name;
            system.debug('title'+cVersion.title);
            cVersion.versionData =blogdecode;
            insert cVersion;    
            ID conDocument = [Select ContentDocumentID from ContentVersion where ID=:cVersion.ID].ContentDocumentID;
           //insert ContentDocumentLink
         
            ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
            conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = '0065Y00001WF9OPQA1';
            conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDocument;
            insert conDocLink;     
             String downUrl;
            String url = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toexternalForm(); //Returns a string representation of the current URL.
            String substring = '.lightning.force.com';
            downUrl= 'https://ds-dev-ed.lightning.force.com'; //  - It is use for get index of string/character from the specified from index.
           return ( downUrl +'/lightning/r/Opportunity/'+cVersion.Id+'/view '); 
       
        } 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It's giving you back a list instead of a single result. Including your observed JSON response would reduce guesswork.

Comment: Check out [How do I get started working with JSON in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex)

Comment: I have also added the debug log to see the response body

Comment: Your screenshot does not help. Please debug `response.getBody()` and include its output *as text*.

Comment: system.debug('response getbody'+res.getBody()); at line no 55 ....after debugging the the output is - USER_DEBUG [55]|DEBUG|response getbody"https://DS-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0685Y00000RctdgQAB/view "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**:
After looking at the updated code in the question:
Looking at your code, I wonder why you need to deserialize in the first place. You are just getting a string from your third-party system, which is available in your resBody variable. You can directly store that in your object.

**Original Answer:** At Line 55, you are deserializing a response to the same wrapper class you used for the Auth response.

```
deserializeResponse resp2 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(trimmedResponse, deserializeResponse.class);
```

You will need to create a new wrapper class for this response, and by the looks of it, your Apex class returns a list, so you need to deserialize this reponse to a `List<YourNewWrapper>()`.

```
List<YourNewWrapper> resp2 = (List<YourNewWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(trimmedResponse, List<YourNewWrapper>.class);
```

Comment: <pre><code>public class deserializeResponse1
    {
        public String id;
    } list<deserializeResponse1> resp2 = (list<deserializeResponse1>)JSON.deserialize(trimmedResponse, list<deserializeResponse1>.class);
           Document_URL__c a = [SELECT Id,Document_URL__c FROM Document_URL__c];
             a.Document_URL__c = resp2.id;
            system.debug('a.Document_URL__c'+a.Document_URL__c);
             update a; <pre><code> while updating this code i got an error as variable id does not exist at the resp2.id how to resolve it

Comment: resp2 is a list. So you need to access a specific index - resp2[0].Id

Comment: thank you ,but still i get the same error Line: 15, Column: 1 System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/set

Comment: Please update the question with the latest version of SendAttachmentByRestAPI, and the Apex class behind the getContentVersions apex rest endpoint

Comment: I have updated the class

Comment: Oh - Looking at your code, I wonder why you need to deserialize in the first place. You are just getting a string from your third-party system, which is available in your resBody variable. You can directly store that in your object.

Comment: thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Your Target Org endpoint is returning a simple String value, `return ( downUrl +'/lightning/r/Opportunity/'+cVersion.Id+'/view ');` not a formatted JSON response. You do not need to de-serialize at all.

The error message is correct, what you are returning is not in JSON format.