# Rest post account record error "POST requires content-length"

Tags: apex, rest, post

So i am trying to insert some account record. Token is right because get command works well. Error while Post -  POST requires content-length. I am even trying to add body with  JSONGenerator.

```
     Http h1 = new Http();
     HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
     req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accesstoken);
     req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
     req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
     JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
     gen.writeStartObject();
     gen.writeObjectField('name', 'Test Account');
     gen.writeEndObject();
     String body = gen.getAsString();
     request.setBody(body);
     req1.setMethod('POST');    
     req1.setEndpoint('url/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/account');
     HttpResponse res1 = h1.send(req1);
     system.debug('RESPONSE_BODY'+res1.getbody());
```

Comment: Take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex for more info on how to create JSON payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no body in `req1`, because you have set it to `request.setBody(body);`. You need to change this line to `req1.setBody(body);` and content-length will appear automatically on request with body. For POST it is required.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Сouldn't see if for 30 minutes)