# Get node value from nested json - Apex

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

I would like to know if exists a better way to get the value of "value" node, this is my code and I think there may be a better way.

```
String jsonTest = '{
      "testNode": {
        "testNodeTwo": {
          "testNodeThree": {
            "value" : "12345"
          }
        }
      }
    }'
    
Map<String,Object> jsonToMap = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonTest);
Map<String,Object> testNode = jsonToMap.get('testNode');
Map<String,Object> testNodeTwo = testNode .get('testNodeTwo');
Map<String,Object> testNodeThree = testNodeTwo.get('testNodeThree');
String value = testNodeThree.get('value').toString();
```

Comment: Rather than using untyped JSON create data transfer object classes and ensure they have (public) properties that reflect the required hierarchy and content, then just deserialize to the type of the top level object's class and use SNO to traverse like `theJson?.testNode?.testNodeTwo?.testNodeThree?.value`.

Comment: Also see the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm)

Comment: Yes! I decided to apply "Generating Code with JSON2Apex" solution from question: 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-ith-json-in-apex
Thank you so much @PhilW

Comment: Great. Personally I hand write the classes myself since there may not be a complete example of all valid variations of the JSON, and I tend to then have a validation method that cascades down through the tree to ensure the JSON is validly specified. I also write JSON schemas that express the validity rules in a way that can be used by a good schema aware editor like VSCode. But then many of our JSON documents are intended for human admin/implementer editing or for REST APIs where the schema helps the client author understand the required structure.