# How to deserialize JSON array into list of objects

Tags: apex, json

I'm getting a JSON array from a REST callout:

```
[{\"name\":\"Jan0\",\"lastName\":\"Test0\",\"id\":0},
 {\"name\":\"Jan1\",\"lastName\":\"Test1\",\"id\":1},
 {\"name\":\"Jan2\",\"lastName\":\"Test2\",\"id\":2},
 {\"name\":\"Jan3\",\"lastName\":\"Test3\",\"id\":3}]
```

This gives me an error:

```
 List<Object> objs = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
```

**FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type String to List**

Ouch. Did I serialize the JSON incorrectly, or am I doing a mistake at covnerting the JSOn to the List?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get started working with JSON in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex)

Comment: @identigral It helps, but it does not exactly point out where I am making a mistake... could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the payload got serialized twice somehow. Ideally you would fix that so it is serialized just once instead. However, you can fix it in the interim by deserializing first into a `String`, then into your `List<Object>`.

```
String payload = (String)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
List<Object> data = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(payload);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were right! May I ask how you figured this out? It does not seem obvious to me.

Comment: @DevelBase2 The escaped double-quotes is indicative of this type of thing. "regular" JSON doesn't do that, it'd just be `[{"name":"Jan0","lastName":"Test0","id":0} ...]`

Comment: @DerekF Hah, brilliant. Thanks!