# Apex error Invalid conversion form type Map<String,ANY> to List<ANY>

Tags: apex

As in the title I don't know why I'm getting error when I'm trying to put API data from Map to List

```
            Map<String,Object> results=(Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            System.debug('Map:'+results);
            List<Object> rates = (List<Object>) results.get('rates');
            System.debug('List:'+rates);
```

Output from the API after console logging Map with commented List:
[image]
Input JSON:

[image]

Error message:

[image]

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Im getting error "Type cannot be constructed: Object"

Comment: can you confirm which object it is returning in the Map?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the input JSON. The error it telling me that the `rates` property is an object, not an array. Look at the JSON. I think you will see `"rates": {` rather than `"rates": [`.

Comment: @PhilW I added input JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rates is an object. `JSON` Object strings convert to `Map<String,Object>`

So the rates line should be:

```
Map<String,Object> rates =(Map<String,Object>) = (List<Object>) results.get('rates');
System.debug('List:'+rates);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON.deserializeUntyped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped) method takes the input [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) string and constructs a standardized structure of Apex class instances from it. This is applied in a recursive manner to handle nesting of JSON structures.

When the JSON includes an object *value*, this is denoted by an open brace - `{` - the content of this object is (as per the specification) and unordered collection of name/value pairs. `JSON.deserializeUntyped` uses a `Map<String, Object>` to represent this. The keys of the map are the *names*, and the values of the map are the associated *values*.

When the JSON includes an array *value*, this is denoted by an open square bracket - `[` - this is an ordered sequence of values and is represented by `List<Object>` in the output from `JSON.deserializeUntyped`.

Values in JSON can be objects, arrays, strings, booleans, numbers (integer or floating point) or the special value of "null".

Apex represents all *value* types using `Object` since this is the base class for all Apex classes/types (though interestingly the error messages use the name `ANY` instead of `Object`).

So, putting this together, when you tried to access the "rates" property from the top-level object in your JSON (itself returned as a `Map<String, Object>` because the JSON document starts with `{`) you tried to take that `Object` and cast it to a `List<Object>`. However, it was actually converted to a `Map<String, Object>` and this is not compatible with being cast to a List - hence the exception. Make sure you do the correct type casting.

```
"rates": {
  "X": ...
```

It is **really** important to note the delimiter and any formatting of the value.

In summary, for `JSON.deserializeUntyped`:

- If the delimiter is `{`, the value is an object (so a `Map<String, Object>` filled with name/value pairs)
- If the delimiter is `[`, the value is an array (so a `List<String>` filled with values).
- Values can be any one of:

  - `Map<String, Object>` - it's an object that starts with `{`
  - `List<Object>` - it's an array of other values that starts with `[`
  - `String` - it's a value in double quotes like `"example"`
  - `Integer` - it's a numeric value like `10`
  - `Double` - it's a numeric value like `10.0`
  - `Boolean` - it's either `true` or `false`
  - `null` - it's `null`

A JSON document contains a *value*. It is common for it to start either with `{` or `[` but this isn't actually mandatory. The document can actually be any type of value (even just a number or string).

NB: The JSON you added to the question is actually invalid; the rate object's property names must be in double quotes to be valid JSON. What you have here is what looks like JavaScript shorthand property names (without quotes).

More info can be found in [this other Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex).