# how to typecast json response into wrapper class

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, apex-webservice

Below is the json response I receive from service provider.

```
{"_embedded":{"Id":"ABC-000","itemSummaries":[{"contractId":"CO11111","endDate":"2024-02-20T15:59:59.000Z","startDate":"2023-02-20T16:00:00.000Z","productAttributes":[{"tier":"standard","type":"listing","region":"kv","duration":"90","countryA2":"my","releaseSchedule":[{"startDate":"2023-02-20T16:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2024-02-20T15:59:59.000Z","statuses":{"provisioned":50,"used":0,"available":50}}]},{"type":"credit","region":"kv","countryA2":"my","releaseSchedule":[{"startDate":"2023-02-20T16:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2024-02-20T15:59:59.000Z","statuses":{"provisioned":50,"used":0,"available":50}}]},{"type":"adcredit","region":"kv","countryA2":"my","releaseSchedule":[{"startDate":"2023-02-20T16:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2024-02-20T15:59:59.000Z","statuses":{"provisioned":50,"used":0,"available":50}}]}]}]}
```

Below is my wrapper class generated from admin booster

```
public class ResponseController{
public class Embedded {
    public String Id;    //ABC-000
    public ItemSummaries[] itemSummaries;
}
public class ItemSummaries {
    public String contractId;   //CO111111
    public String endDate;  //2024-02-20T15:59:59.000Z
    public String startDate;    //2023-02-20T16:00:00.000Z
    public ProductAttributes[] productAttributes;
}
public class ProductAttributes {
    public String tier; //standard
    public String type; //listing
    public String region;   //kv
    public String duration; //90
    public String countryA2;    //my
    public ReleaseSchedule[] releaseSchedule;
}
public class ReleaseSchedule {
    public String startDate;    //2023-02-20T16:00:00.000Z
    public String endDate;  //2024-02-20T15:59:59.000Z
    public Statuses statuses;
}
public class Statuses {
    public Integer provisioned; //50
    public Integer used;    //0
    public Integer available;   //50
}

public static ResponseController parse(String json){
    return (ResponseController) System.JSON.deserialize(json, ResponseController.class);
}
}
```

Below is my controller where I'm trying to typecast the response.

```
ResponseController resp = ResponseController.parse(response.getBody());
System.Debug('resp###' + resp);
```

But I'm getting empty in the logs. Can anyone please tell me what am I missing here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get started working with JSON in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex)

Comment: @identigral I followed the same as mentioned in JSON2Apex section of your suggested link. But I don't what am I missing here.

Comment: I see no property called "_embedded" in your "controller" class.

Comment: Yup my bad ! its fine now. Thanks for pointing out