# Extract Particular value from the result list and store them in another list

Tags: apex, json, loop, nested

Hi I have a list type of List which is returned from the invocable action.

List<Invocable.Action.Result> results = action.invoke();

I am getting the data as below in the form of result.

```
(Result":[
   "action=Action":[
      "invocations=("{
         "QuestionDevName=testA",
         "ResponeValue=WBFH"
      }")",
      "invokeFromLightningComponent=false",
      "name=Tser",
      "namespace=null",
      "type=runDecisionMatrix"
   ],
   "errors=()",
   "invocationParameters=(already output)",
   "outputParameters="{
      IndividualScore=20.0
   },
   "success=true"
])
```

Kindly help me to take out the IndividualScore and store in another list in below List testInteger = new List();

Trying below approach as

```
testInteger = results.get(Result.outputParameters.IndividualScore);
```

Comment: Since this is JSON format, you'll want to use the JSON class to deserialize this into a wrapper class where you can access the data easily.  See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex

Comment: @DavidCheng It's not JSON, it's Action.Result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the getOutputParameters() on the results.

```
Integer[] testInteger = new Integer[0];
for(Invocable.Action.Result result: results) {
  testInteger.add((Integer)result.getOutputParameters().get('IndividualScore'));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much @sfdcfox :), i was trying to crack this from 4hrs ,.