# JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object Error is in expression '{!TrackCovd}' in component

Tags: apex, integration, json

When I use a api using I check all the code twice time but not get where the problems occurs when I fetch the result is find only null because of this is a problem statement

> System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object
> Error is in expression '{!TrackCovd}' in component apex:commandButton in page indiancovidtracker: (System Code)
> Class.Indiancovid1trackerController.TrackCovd: line 59, column 1

here is Controller code

```java
public class Indiancovid1trackerController {
    Public String jsonResponse{get;set;}
    Public List<Covidstatedeltails> lstcovid{get;set;}
             
    public void TrackCovd() {
      
        lstcovid = new List<Covidstatedeltails>();
        
        string endPointURL = 'https://india-covid19vaccine.github.io/api/state_latest.json';
        
        HttpRequest pRequest = new HttpRequest();
       
        pRequest.setEndpoint(endPointURL);
        pRequest.setMethod('GET');
        pRequest.setTimeout(12000);
         
        HttpResponse pResponse = new HttpResponse();
         
        Http pHttp = new Http();
        pResponse = pHttp.send(pRequest);
         
        jsonResponse = pResponse.getBody();
      
        System.JSONParser pParser = System.JSON.createParser(pResponse.getBody());
      
        while(pParser.nextToken() != null)
        {
            if(pParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME && pParser.getText() == 'State')
            {
                pParser.nextToken();
                System.debug('State' + pParser.getText());
            }
            else if(pParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME && pParser.getText() == 'state_code')
            {
                pParser.nextToken();
                System.debug('state_code' + pParser.getText());
            }
            else if(pParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME && pParser.getText() == 'total_doses')
            {
                pParser.nextToken();
                System.debug('total_doses' + pParser.getText());
            }
            else if(pParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME && pParser.getText() == 'total_vaccinated')
            {
                pParser.nextToken();
                System.debug('total_vaccinated' + pParser.getText());
            }
            else if(pParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME && pParser.getText() == 'total_fully_vaccinated')
            {
                pParser.nextToken();
                System.debug('total_fully_vaccinated' + pParser.getText());
            }
            else if(pParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME && pParser.getText() == 'population')
            {
                pParser.nextToken();
                System.debug('population ' + pParser.getText());
            }
    
            covidstatedeltails CovidInfo = (covidstatedeltails)pParser.readValueAs(covidstatedeltails.class);
            lstcovid.Add(CovidInfo);
            pParser.nextToken();
        }
    }
}
```

The line the error is complaining about is `covidstatedeltails CovidInfo = (covidstatedeltails)pParser.readValueAs(covidstatedeltails.class);`

Comment: Do you know what the structure of the response is going to be? If so you're probably better off deserialising into a set type, rather than looping over the tokens.

Comment: @fred can You elaborate some more bcoz i m new

Comment: If you know what the structure of the response is going to be you can use `JSON.deserialize`. Have a read here: https://sfdclesson.com/2023/01/24/exploring-the-different-methods-of-parsing-json-in-apex/

Comment: Please check this [canonical qa](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/302034/62544)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get started working with JSON in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex)

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, the issue is that you're telling Salesforce to deserialize the JSON into a single instance of `covidstatedeltails`
but the JSON you're using is a *list of `CovidStateDeltails`*

This is pretty basic JSON knowledge.
If the JSON starts with `{`, then it's a single object.
If the JSON starts with `[`, then it's a list of objects (a.k.a. an array of objects)

The JSON you're getting from that github link starts like

```
[{"state":"A & N Islands", ...
```

It starts with `[`, therefore it is a list, and you need to treat it like a list.

Beyond that, you should not be using `System.JSONParser` in 99.9% of cases. It's overly verbose and prone to making mistakes (especially if you don't know what you're doing).

`System.JSON.deserialize()` is generally the way to go.
Pass in your JSON string, tell it what class to deserialize into, cast the result into your target class, and you're done.

As a brief example, let's deserialize some JSON of a list of books

```java
public class SomeApexClass {
    String myJSON = '[{"title":"To Kill A Mockingbird","author":"Harper Lee"},{"title":"The Compendious Book on Calculation by Completion and Balancing","author":"Muhammad ibn Musa Al-khwarazmi"}]';

    // To deserialize, you need one Apex class for each JSON "object"
    // i.e. something enclosed by curly braces
    public class Book {
        // Each attribute in the JSON that you want to deserialize needs
        //   to be a member variable
        String title;
        String author;
    }

    public List<Book> deserializeBooks() {
        // Since we're dealing with a JSON list, we need to treat it like a list

        // Each individual object in the list is a Book, so we need to end up with a
        //   list of Book instances
        List<Book> results;

        // We need to tell the deserialize method that it should expect a list of books
        //   so we pass in "List<Book>.class"
        // The result of deserialization is always an "Object", so we need to do
        //   a little explicit type-casting (the "(List<Book>)" part) to assign it
        //   to something we can use later
        results = (List<Book>)JSON.deserialize(myJSON, List<Book>.class);

        Assert.areEqual('Harper Lee', results[0].author);
    }
}
```

For most cases, using [the JSON2Apex site](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) is going to be the easiest way to take arbitrary JSON and get it into a workable state in Apex.